# Why do I receive so many password reset/welcome emails from services I'm not a customer of?

Tags: password-management, account-security, multi-factor

Over the years I've received the occasional password reset from a service I've never used (or even heard of sometimes). As far as I can tell, the emails are genuinely being generated and sent by the service. Still, I always ignore them.

But, more recently, this has been ramping up, to the point where I recevied *dozens* of password reset emails from Apple within a few hours. I do have and have never had an account with any of Apple's services.

So, *why* am I getting these? Is this some kind of attack? What is the aim/goal of this? Is there anything I can do about this, or should I just continue to ignore all of it?

Comment: If someone were to make up a quick bogus email address like *smith@hotmail.com*, what are the odds that your email might match a made up one?

Comment: We get a question like this every month. It is most likely that someone is entering your email address by mistake when asking for an email reset.

Comment: And that someone is probably wondering why Apple isn't sending them a password reset to 'their' email account

Comment: It's very unlikely that someone _accidentally_ used my email address, since it's not common (i.e., unlike what @user10216038 suggested above), so I'm not particularly convinced by that explanation. Even considering the law of large numbers, I find it unlikely.

Comment: @schroeder Can you point/link to similar questions to this one? I honestly searched for a while, but couldn't find anything similar. Perhaps my search terms weren't quite right?